# Getting '404 Not Found Nginx' while trying to visit Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a NodeJS app deployed in the root of my domain (example.com) and I'm struggling for the last 7 days to add a blog in a subdirectory (example.com/blog). Even though I have set it up but I think there is some issue with Nginx config as I can't access the blog posts (blog homepage is accessible). It is also worth mentioning that I CAN access the posts if I set Permalinks to Plain in Wordpress settings, which I don't want because of SEO.

If I look at error logs then I can see this:

```
2022/09/02 15:43:43 [error] 86838#86838: *6 "/var/www/html/example.com/blog/advantages-of-social-media-2/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 142.52.23.144, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /blog/advantages-of-social-media-2/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/blog/"
```

Wordpress installation is located in `/var/www/html/example.com/blog` but in the config I have not added `/blog` but I can still access the blog homepage. And if I add it, then I can't access it anymore.

I tried like a million different solutions but nothing seems to be working. Someone please help me out.

Here's the full Nginx config without the SSL statements:

```
server {

       server_name example.com;
       return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;    

}

server {

        server_name www.example.com;

        # NodeJS App
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # Wordpress Blog
        location /blog {

                access_log /var/log/nginx/blog_access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/blog_error.log;

                root /var/www/html/example.com;
                index index.php;

                # Add a trailing slash if missing
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
                }
                
                # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                # try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

                location ~ \.php {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        # Change this to your fpm socket
                        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;

                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: Your first server block is listening (presumably) on 80, and returns the secure `https` URI. Where is the block that's listening to pick up that return? e.g. `listen 443 ssl http2; server_name examplel.com; ssl on;`?

Comment: @Bman70 I removed those here to keep it clean and simple. SSL and everything is configured perfectly.

Comment: you maybe having some `.htaccess` redirection in the wordpress directory. try commenting them if exists.

Comment: @AniketDas I don't have .htaccess.  :(

Comment: @AniketDas Oh wait. I do have a .htaccess in my wordpress directory. Please check the OP for what's inside it.

Comment: @AniketDas Commented that only line of code in `.htaccess`, still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, dont just copy and paste this and try to understand what each block do

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    
    #Addition Configs
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
    error_log /var/www/html/example.com/error error;

    root /var/www/html/example.com;
    index  index.html index.php;

    location / {
        gzip_static on;
        error_page 418 = @cachemiss;
        .
        .
        .
    }

    location @cachemiss {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    ### DISABLE LOGGING ###
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    ### CACHES ###
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|mp4)$ { access_log off; expires max; }
    location ~* \.(woff|svg|woff2|ttf|eot)$ { access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 30d; }
    location ~* \.(js)$ { access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 7d; }
    
    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    ### php block ###
    location ~ \.php?$ {
        fastcgi_cache phpcache; 
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m;
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; 
        
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

The most important part you have to configure is the `php-block/fast-cgi` location block which you should directly put under server block and outside the `blog` location

Then on your `blog` location just do a request to `/blog/index.php`
like so;

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

your directory structure should be;

```
/var/www/html/example.com - your root folder which should contains any app you want
/var/www/html/example.com/blog - contains your wordpress installation
```

for fastcgi caching, you either remove this line
`fastcgi_cache phpcache;` from php block,

or go to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and configure fastcgi caching like below;
the code below should be in `http` block

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed answer. However, I had a question regarding my Nodejs apps config here in Nginx. Nodejs apps doesn't have any root or files path and currently my Nodejs app resides in `/home/user/` directory. Besides that if you see my config, my Nodejs app's config is in side location / but in your config you put some other configs. Can I put my config in there?

Comment: just replace my example root location to your own, the most important part would be to tell nginx where is the root directory, where is the blog directory and the php-cgi config

Comment: Hey, I'll give it a try now however, I had two other questions for learning purposes. Why did you put `/var/www/html/example.com` as root whereas my blog is located at `/var/www/html/example.com/blog`? Another question is, is 9000 default port for fastcgi_pass? How will I understand which port it is running on?

Comment: for the root; your server block will assume the root folder for your server_name, so if you open `example.com/blog`, it will look for the directory `blog` which should be inside your root folder. re port 9000, Im just using tcp port for `fast_cgi` directive on my example, you can use your unix socket like on your config `fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;` just make sure this file `/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock` exist

Comment: Hey just tried your config but I'm getting this nginx error: `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_cache" zone "phpcache" is unknown in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:70
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
`

Comment: I edited my answer, my example assume you configure fastcgi caching, you either replace that `phpcache` with your cache key or remove that line entirely and disable fastcgi caching

Comment: hey man, I'm having issues with the lines of code that are under cachemiss, disable logging and caches. They are being applied to my main app in the root domain (example.com). The app's js and css files are not found and the pages are simple html pages. If I comment them out then it goes back to normal. How can I let them only apply to my Wordpress site in /blog and not my main app in /?

Comment: you can remove the `@cachemeiss` on the, main location and apply it on  `/blog` location. also, check why the files are 404, go to nework tab, check the header, and if the files being pulled are correct URL